# How to get all possible paths in a tree model

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, tree, tree-traversal

I am looking for a way to get all possible paths of a tree/network model using Ruby.

Example of my model:

[image: Network]

What I need is a list of all possible paths:

1. ACG
2. ACH
3. ADG
4. ADH
5. ABEG
6. ABEH
7. ABFG
8. ABFH

Each node has a list of child nodes. Number of child nodes can be 0..x

Seems very trivial, but I haven't found a way to do this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I managed to get same result with this:

```
def get_paths(ret_data, list = "")
  children = get_children
  list += description

  if children.count == 0
    ret_data.push(list)
  end

  children.each do |c|
    c.get_paths(ret_data, list)
  end
end

data = []
first_node.get_paths(data)

data ====>

[
 "ACG",
 "ACH",
 "ADG",
 "ADH",
 "ABEG",
 "ABEH",
 "ABFG",
 "ABFH"
]
```

Result ok, but if I push node's description into a array in get_paths method the result is strange:

```
 def get_paths(ret_data, list = [])
  children = get_children

   list << description

   if children.count == 0
    ret_data.push(list)
   end

   children.each do |c|
     c.get_paths(ret_data, list)
   end
 end

 data = []
 first_node.get_paths(data)

 data ====>

 [
  [
    "A",
    "C",
    "G",
    "H",
    "D",
    "G",
    "H",
    "B",
    "E",
    "G",
    "H",
    "F",
    "G",
    "H"
],
[
    "A",
    "C",
    "G",
    "H",
    "D",
    "G",
    "H",
    "B",
    "E",
    "G",
    "H",
    "F",
    "G",
    "H"
],
[data like above],[data like above]....,
[
    "A",
    "C",
    "G",
    "H",
    "D",
    "G",
    "H",
    "B",
    "E",
    "G",
    "H",
    "F",
    "G",
    "H"
]]

number of paths ok (8), but data inside paths wrong
```

What happens when pushing node's descriptions into array?

Comment: Recursively visiting each subtree should give you all paths.

Comment: Note that `B->F` is a path. Your example shows what you want, but it's always best to be precise with your words: "What I need is a list of all possible paths from nodes with no incoming arcs to nodes with no outgoing arcs".  Nice-looking graph.

Comment: The graph is not a tree...

Comment: No idea what is the right term for the "tree". It is a?

Comment: A better term could be "directed acyclic graph". In a tree, each node only has one parent.

Comment: When you do _list += description_, you are creating a new string object at each recursive call. (a+=b is syntactic sugar for a=a+b.) When you do _list << description_, you are not creating any objects, just using the same array object throughout the entire recursion through the graph. Hence the values for the previous branch will still be there when you take the next branch. You could fix it by using something like _list=list+[description]_ or _list+=[description]_ or _list=[list,description].flatten_.

Comment: First of all its not a tree by definition. A tree cannot have more than one path between two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You should post some code showing how your tree is represented. Here I just invented a structure using hashes.

```
h={:name=>"H", :children=>[]}
g={:name=>"G", :children=>[]}
f={:name=>"F", :children=>[g,h]}
e={:name=>"E", :children=>[g,h]}
d={:name=>"D", :children=>[g,h]}
c={:name=>"C", :children=>[g,h]}
b={:name=>"B", :children=>[e,f]}
a={:name=>"A", :children=>[b,c,d]}

def paths(node,path='',&proc)
  if node[:children].empty?
    proc.call(path+node[:name])
  else
    node[:children].each{|c| paths(c,path+node[:name],&proc)}
  end
end

paths(a){|path|
  puts path
}
```

This is a basic depth-first-search, keeping track of the path so far and calling the given block on leaf nodes.

Comment: I would suggest `paths(path = '', node, &proc)` so you can call with `paths(a) {|path| puts path}`, but why not just `def paths(node, path = ''); if node[:children].size ==0; puts path + node[:name]; else; node[:children].each { |c| paths(c, path + node[:name]) }` and call with `paths(a)`? I also suggest you use `array.empty?` rather than `array.size==0`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree with the default value (also need to switch the parameter order) and empty? method. Answer edited. I like using a block because it allows doing any operations instead of just printing the paths. E.g. you could implement _each_ using the paths method (or just rename it) and _include Enumerable_ to get all the ruby iteration methods to cycle through the paths.

Comment: You don't need to change the parameter order, at least in recent versions of Ruby. Ruby is pretty smart about that.  If it sees that two parameters are passed, and two parameters do not have defaults, it will know what to do.